# Dynamically add links with different click events

Tags: javascript, closures

I have an extension which adds several links on a page dynamically, and all the links should trigger the same function but with diffrent parameter values.

The problem I got is that the click event sends the same variable for all my links (the last item's url gets sent for every link). I belive the click event gets overwritten each time. Is there any solution for this?

```
for(var i=1;i < splits.length;i++){               //goes through all xml items.
    var link_dom = document.createElement('a');   //creates a link dom.
    var url = parseXMLItem(splits[i],"url");      //fetches url from xml item i.
    var text_dom = document.createTextNode("test"); //creates a text dom.

    link_dom.onclick=function (evt) {             //click event for this specific link.
        chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'showSite','URL' : url}, mysub);
    }

    link_dom.appendChild(text_dom);               //adds text to link.
    body_dom.appendChild(link_dom);               //adds the link to the website.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure is referencing the variable in the outer context, which is reassigned on every loop iteration. Try something like this:

```
for(var i=1;i < splits.length;i++){               //goes through all xml items.
    var link_dom = document.createElement('a');   //creates a link dom.
    var url = parseXMLItem(splits[i],"url");      //fetches url from xml item i.
    var text_dom = document.createTextNode("test"); //creates a text dom.

    link_dom.onclick=(function(url) {
        return function (evt) {             //click event for this specific link.
            chrome.extension.sendRequest({'action' : 'showSite','URL' : url}, mysub);
        }
    })(url);

    link_dom.appendChild(text_dom);               //adds text to link.
    body_dom.appendChild(link_dom);               //adds the link to the website.
}
```